# How to put a image in a pdf using itext library in android?

Tags: android, itext

I have a `png` image in drawable folder and I want to use that `png` image in the `pdf` . I am using `itextpdf.jar` for creating the `pdf`. I searched for solution ,but I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try {
            InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                    "launchscreen.png");
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Image signature;
            signature = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            signature.setAbsolutePosition(400f, 150f);
            signature.scalePercent(100f);
            document.add(signature);
                    document.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: its showing me this error.
05-15 14:04:09.008: E/AndroidRuntime(28222): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tag.texttopdf/com.tag.texttopdf.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.content.res.AssetManager$AssetInputStream cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.Base64$InputStream

Comment: on this line 
InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                    "launchscreen.png");
its showing me error and saying to add cast to inputStream. Any idea?

Comment: just changed to
 java.io.InputStream inputStream = MainActivity.this.getAssets().open(
                     "radiobuttonoff.png");

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Image image = Image.getInstance(yourImageByteArray);

document.add(image);
```

where `document` is an object of `Document`